# what will happend to my files if I uninstalled SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-server

I want to know what will happened if I add some docs / files in SVN repository and then uninstall SVN ? Will my data in repository lost ?

What about working copy of data ? will it lost as well or it will remain ?

If I add my files in SVN and then copy its working copy on some other folder on computer will new copy also attached to SVN  or it will be independent copy ?

**Edit:**

I am new to SVN. I just installed SVN server on my computer and then Tortise svn and Ankh SVN. When I was adding a project from my visual studio to SVN it shows some error. I uninstalled SVN and then restarted my computer.

On restarting and newly installing SVN I set a different directory as repository and then I found that my working copy is also not there any more. Main folder was there but files were not.

I was working on this project from last week and it is lost now. Kindly guide and help me, is there some way that I can get my files back ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SVN is just a client over a working copy which is just a copy of server (repository) files.

You can uninstall client, that will not touch working copy.

You can delete (commit everything first, probably) working copy, that will not touch the repository itself.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing will happen to your repository and your working copy when you uninstall SVN. I assume you are uninstalling to get another version in? Just make sure it is not too different a version or your working copy / repo may not be compatible

Comment: thanks for replying.

Yester day what happened was I uninstalled SVN server and it also removed working copies from my system. I lost my precious data. Any guidline please ?

Comment: @user576510 - that should not happen! Please add more detail to your question on what you did. BTW, why are you asking what will happen AFTER uninstalling SVN?